# Reading Excel Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I am trying to read the contents of excel macro using Pandas.

[image]

Below is the code.

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"Temp.xls")`

But the result is null.

`Empty DataFrame
Columns: [<CrystalAddin Version="1" country="FR" lang="fr"/>]
Index: []`

Please help me.

Comment: Just checking, is the filename correct? Because macro-enabled workbooks have a `.xlsm` extension.

Comment: I have checked the format. It is '.xls'.

Comment: Then if .xls  it won’t contain a macro, unless the nacro is stored in the “personal” file.

Comment: File format is '.xls'. Inside excel there is a button which can used to get latest update from server.

Comment: So, where is the code the button references? I put my codes into "personal.xlsm" then I know where to find them and my ".xlsx" files are "flat"... As I share files and some have security settings that block macros in workbooks.

Comment: Could you please be more precise about what you mean by "read the contents of excel macro". I understand this to mean you want to extract the macro code from the file. Do you mean you're trying to *execute* a macro? And are you sure the library you're using can work with the xls file format? That's the old, binary file format. All the documentation I see refers to the file format xlsx - the Open Office XML file format. Try saving the file in Excel to the xlsx (or xlsm) file format and see if you get a better result.